# SQL joins and Subqueries , Subquery to SQL joins

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, join, subquery

I wrote this SQL query to get friends of user who is not in the invitation table , and it works will , however i read that subqueries are performance eaters and I am not very good with JOINS, any help for modifying this query to be just in joins will be really appreciated.

**Here is the SQL Query**

```
SELECT friend.id,
       friend.first_name
FROM   friends AS friend
       INNER JOIN friends_users AS friendsUser
         ON ( friend.id = friendsUser.friend_id
              AND friend.id NOT IN (SELECT friend_id
                                    FROM   friends_invitations
                                    WHERE  friends_invitations.user_id = 1) )
ORDER  BY friendsUser.id ASC
```

**Here is the tables structure**

```
friends
id   first_name

friends_users
id  friend_id  user_id

friends_invitations
id  friend_id user_id
```

Any help will be really appreciated

Comment: If you have a question about performance you should tag the RDBMS you are using as well (e.g. Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL) . SQL is declarative. How it is optimised depends upon the product you are using.

Comment: A JOIN can not necessarily be re-written as a sub-select. And a DBMS with a decent Optimizer will do that automatically if it thinks it will improve performance.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I am using MySQL does it do that ?

Comment: No, the optimizer in MySQL is pretty dumb - especially with sub-select

Answer (score 1):

A subquery is not necessarily a performance eater, is your query presenting performance issues?. Anyway, most times the fastest way to do your query would be using a `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT  friend.id, 
        friend.first_name 
FROM friends AS friend 
INNER JOIN friends_users AS friendsUser 
    ON friend.id = friendsUser.friend_id  
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM friends_invitations 
                  WHERE friends_invitations.user_id = 1
                  AND friend_id = friend.id)
ORDER BY friendsUser.id ASC
```

[Here is a link](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/) explaining the differences between `NOT IN`, `LEFT JOIN` and `NOT EXISTS` (for SQL Server). So, test this different options and choose the right one for your tables.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `LEFT JOIN` for this,

```
SELECT  friend.id,
        friend.first_name
FROM    friends AS friend
        INNER JOIN friends_users AS friendsUser
            ON friend.id = friendsUser.friend_id 
        LEFT JOIN   friends_invitations
            ON friend.id = friends_invitations.friend_id AND
                friends_invitations.user_id = 1
WHERE   friends_invitations.friend_id IS NULL
ORDER   BY friendsUser.id ASC
```

Comment: if you have properly define an index on columns where the search takes place, then you don't have to worry. here's an statement from some links: `LEFT JOIN / IS NULL and NOT EXISTS are semantically equivalent, while NOT IN is not.`

Comment: how does it differ from your expected result?